# Can't update error E type libe 58

Tags: package-management, update-manager, ppa

Can't open update manger,package manager or software center.

1. The following code appears when I attempt to launch the above:

> ```
> Could not initialize the package information
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> 'E:Type '“deb' is not known on line 58 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list, E:The list of sources could not be read.'
> ```

Tried to 'gedit' it, apparently it doesn't handle 'E' Files?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried other softwares, like sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list ? The file might be too large for gedit to handle? : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1008062

Answer (score 1):

Line 58 of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems to start with `“deb` instead of `deb`.

Open the file as root in an editor, for example using

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

from the command line, and remove the `“` (and if there's a `”` at the end of the line remove that, too).

Comment: Everything appears ok there, no "deb' as such.

Comment: Believe this is it: “deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lkucid main”
“deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main”
“deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main”
“deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main”
“deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main”
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org Karmic main

Comment: Can I hi-light that & simply delete them to restore functioning of my update manger,package manager & software center.?

Comment: If you don't need this repositories anymore you can delete them. It may be a good idea to make a copy of the file before. If deleting the lines doesn't help please add the file's content to your question.